# Android remote device management without internet

Tags: android, device-admin, android-enterprise, android-enterprise-features

I'm trying to implement Android device administration on a range of company-owned devices. The network these devices will be on does **not** have an internet connection - It will only have Wi-Fi connection to the enterprise network.

I have the device working with a policy controller, all hard-coded into the app loaded via Android Studio.

My next step is creating an Enterprise Mobility Management (EMM) console, but the documentation seems to explain that it's cloud-based and require Google accounts. Is there a way to implement this functionality on an offline secure network without Google accounts?

Comment: Question is probably off topic, but I'll bite: What are your connection options? If you have none then it boils down to "How do I connect to a machine that has no connections"

Comment: My apologies, I should have specified. The only available connection options in this environment will be Wi-Fi and NFC. All other options have been removed from the device in my custom Android ROM.

Comment: If the devices are not connected to the _Internet_, then you will have two options that I see. Either have a Man-In-The-Middle server which will facilitate the connections between your _Intranet_ devices, and the Google services in the cloud, or, roll your own / license an MDM which will run off of a server on your companies internal network. You will need _some sort of manager_, whether it be Google in the cloud, or a server local to your enterprise network.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way to implement device management functionality on an offline network.

[Headwind MDM](https://h-mdm.com), the project I am working on, is a self hosted mobile device management solution which can manage Android devices without Internet connection (using Wi-Fi or private APN in mobile networks). Also, it is open source so you can adjust the code for your needs.

The only exception is that you may need Internet connection during the initial setup of your Android devices, because some models require access to Google servers when installing the device owner application (to initialize Google Mobile Services).

Answer (score 0):

Soti MobiControl support also onprem installation and Android devices management without need of Google account

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).